# Confused with F# List.nth's argument order

Tags: f#

**List.nth** is **'T list -> int -> 'T**, rather than the standard **int -> 'T list -> 'T** like **Seq.nth**.

This makes pipeline somewhat awkward.

Is there something behind the scene?

I don't know why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Might be for [ocaml compatibility](http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~dmatusze/resources/ocaml/ocaml.html#Operations%20on%20lists) (or just laziness), but without deeper reasons concerning the implementation itself.

Answer (score 1):

This signature allows you to curry the function with respect to a given list. This allows you to keep a List.nth someList stored, and use it to get the nth element of the list without having to specify the list variable every time.

I'm not sure why it's nonuniform with respect to other F# functions, though.

Comment: I guess it wouldn't make much sense to do it that way round with Seq, because you can't really have random access to a Seq.